# testng_failed.xml does not get refreshed before running and run older failed testcases

Tags: maven, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

Actually question related to testng-failed.xml has already been asked many times but my problem is little different. I want to run all the failed test cases together so what i did is in my pom I passed testng-failed.xml.

But the problem I am facing is first my testng.xml runs then testng-failed.xml and then it testng-failed.xml gets overridden. Due to this , suppose if i give a second time fresh run to my testcases, testng.xml runs, then my testng-failed.xml has previously failed test cases so it runs the previously failed cases and then updates testng-failed.xml with this time failed cases.

I dont knoe which listener to add to handle this issue that whenever i run first testng.xml should run , then it should override testng-failed.xml and then testng-failed.xml should run.
I am using Maven, selenium, testng.

I just eneterd testng-failed.xml in my pom as shown below. Please let me know which listner to use

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/resources/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        <suiteXmlFile>test-output/testng-failed.xml</suiteXmlFile> 
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

Comment: If you want to do it in better way then you can try it with "Listener", you can create a listener in which after your test suite will finished it will analyze failed test cases and re-run. advantage of implementing listener is that if you can run multiple times failed test cases , so one can predict exactly number of failed test cases.                                                                                           i hope it will help you. Thanx

Comment: Hi Sahil, I tried "TestNG IRetryAnalyzer" listener but here my test cases are running immediatly it fails. If you could help me with the code as in which listener I should try and how should I override methods in that, it would be gr8 help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create class 'RetryListener' by implementing 'IAnnotationTransformer'.

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {

@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation testannotation, Class testClass,
        Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    IRetryAnalyzer retry = testannotation.getRetryAnalyzer();

    if (retry == null)  {
        testannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(Retry.class);
    }

}
}
```

Now Create another class.

```
public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
private int retryCount = 0;
private int maxRetryCount = 1;

// Below method returns 'true' if the test method has to be retried     
   else 'false' 
//and it takes the 'Result' as parameter of the test method that just 
   ran
 public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        System.out.println("Retrying test " + result.getName() + " with status "
                + getResultStatusName(result.getStatus()) + " for the " + (retryCount+1) + " time(s).");
        retryCount++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String getResultStatusName(int status) {
    String resultName = null;
    if(status==1)
        resultName = "SUCCESS";
    if(status==2)
        resultName = "FAILURE";
    if(status==3)
        resultName = "SKIP";
    return resultName;
  }
  }
```

And Now Add below lines in your testNG xml file

```
   <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.pack.test.RetryListener"/>
   </listeners>
```

and Do not pass Xml file in pom.xml

Hope it will works

Thanks

Comment: On implementing the above listener it runs the failed test case immediatly after it fails. I am looking for something which run all the failed test cases together at the end of first run

Comment: what do you mean by 'run all the failed test cases together' . you want to run failed test cases parallel or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you  running the testng xml and failed test xml in the same testng task. You should have to separate build task, first that runs testng xml and generates the failed tests xml and then another task running the failed test xml. It will work.

Comment: Hi Shamik, Actually I can run 2 different build task but that I can do only from jenkins, But i want to try rhis locally so in my maven project how do I do that as in how can i give two tasks in same pom.??

Comment: @cathaline I have never used maven. But have done something similar in ant , using build.xml. It should be similar in nature. Can you show the pom.xml. It has to run separately in to separate tasks to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented run one time and rerun three times only the newly failed tests.

```
mvn $par1=$pSuiteXmlFile test > $test1log
mvn $par1=$failedRelPath test > $failed1log
mvn $par1=$failedRelPath test > $failed2log
mvn $par1=$failedRelPath test > $failed3log
```

It works, but with small test-cases-count. I have a suite with 300 tests in it and somehow the testng-failed.xml is not created by surefire/testng after the main (first) run. When the suite is smaller, the testng-failed.xml is created as required.